# Android app with multiple activities

Tags: android, android-activity, android-manifest

I have a very simple game that consists of only one activity, and I want to add a title screen.

If the title screen is another activity, what changes do I need to make to my manifest file to make the title screen open first?

The gameplay activity is called Leeder, and the title screen activity is called LeederTitleScreen

here is my current manifest file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="org.nifong.leeder"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0">
    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity android:name="Leeder"
                  android:label="@string/app_name"
                  android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
                  android:screenOrientation="landscape">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="5" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All you should have to do is change:

```
<activity android:name="Leeder"
```

to:

```
<activity android:name="LeederTitleScreen"
```

If you want your title screen to start the game via `startActivity()`, you'll also need to declare your `Leeder` activity in the manifest.

**Edit**: Yes, you need the <intent-filter> section.  It tells the system which implicit intents your activity will respond to.  So in your manifest, the intent filter tells the system that it will respond to the `android.intent.category.LAUNCHER` intent, which is what Android dispatches when it starts an app (i.e. it tells Android to start the Activity when the application is started).

[Here](http://developer.android.com/intl/fr/guide/topics/intents/intents-filters.html) is a good overview of intents and intent filters.

Comment: What is that intent-filter for? do I even need that?

Comment: Edited my answer to be a bit more in-depth.